# Retrofit2: how to retreive value from response and access it? Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I have this response from the server:

```
[
 {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz"
  }
]
```

So I want to access the **name** of the response coming to my android from  the server and make Toast it. So i tried this `onResponse` but it showing nothing:

```
override fun onResponse(call: retrofit2.Call<List<DriverModel>>,
                    response: Response<List<DriverModel>>) 
{

       if (response.body()?.isEmpty()!!) 
       {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "The Response is empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
       }else{

           Toast.makeText(applicationContext, response.body()?.name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
       }
 }
```

so this **Model** class

```
class DriverModel {

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("id")
    val id: Int = 0

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("name")
    val name: String = ""

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("username")
    val username: String = ""
}
```

and this **Api Interface**

```
interface ApiInterface {
   @GET("users")
   fun check( @Query("username") username: String ): Call<FakeUserModel>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`response.body()` returns a list. You can access to the name like this:
`response.body()[0].name`

Comment: Thanks dude, that helped... but why did you use `[0]`  why no just `response.body().name`, explain this please?

Comment: The response from the server return a list of only one element. Access to an element of a list in Kotlin is like that ```[index]``` with index equal to the position of your element (in your case 0). If you want that ```response.body().name``` work then the response from the server should be an object (without brackets)